# Which is best javascript file uploader?

Tags: javascript, file, uploader

I am creating a asp.net MVC web application where i need to implement a artwork file uploader control. What is best AJAX driven file uploader library that is best fit for MVC architecture ? jQuery & Bootstrap are in place already.

Comment: please define 'best'

Comment: Here, i am referring Best to the way by which 1. whole page does not get refreshed. 2. Library footprint is minimum.

Comment: Why do you need a library at all?

Comment: Asking for libraries is typically offtopic on SO.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try and Use iframe and regular fileupload control to upload files asynchronously. This may solve your problem